Which MS Graph permissions are Entra ID members granted by default and are they related to their assigned roles?
Consider the following Azure CLI command for fetching an access token for MS Graph after signing into the Azure:
az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph
In this case, the access token has the following permissions with an audience of https://graph.microsoft.com/:
"scp": "AuditLog.Read.All Directory.AccessAsUser.All email Group.ReadWrite.All openid profile User.ReadWrite.All"
How do I see in Entra ID that my user is assigned these MS Graph permissions? Are they related to my user's assigned Entra ID roles? If so, where do I see the mapping from roles to MS Graph permissions?
Thanks in advance!

When you decode the access-token, you can get the "app_displayname": "Microsoft Azure CLI", and "scp": "AuditLog.Read.All Directory.AccessAsUser.All email Group.ReadWrite.All openid profile User.ReadWrite.All". which means this service principal has the permission of the scp. For general service principals you can find this in Enterprise applications  -> xxx_app_name -> Security -> Permission -> user consent
But some microsoft called first-party service principal are not always list in your tenant. And Microsoft Azure CLI is the one.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/entra/entra-id/governance/verify-first-party-apps-sign-in#verify-a-first-party-microsoft-service-principal-in-your-microsoft-entra-tenant
You can find some login infomations in Microsoft Entra Id sigin-in logs, but you can not find this service principal in Microsoft Entra Id as microsoft told it is first-party microsoft service principal.

First-party Microsoft applications don't always result in a service principal that's created in your tenant. In this case, you'll likely continue to see the applications in your sign-in reports.


Thank you! So, it’s actually the Azure CLI that has been preauthorized for those MS Graph scopes?  The user is not asked for consent

Is MS Graph also a first-party service principal?

So, it’s not possible to change the scopes for Azure CLI?

MS graph seems not be the first-party sp, you can search microsoft graph in you enterprise applications. I do not think you can change the scope of Azure CLI.
